# SQL index on a sum of columns - is that possible?

Tags: sql, performance, indexing

Given two tables, `T1` with column `a` and `T2` with column `b`, is it possible to apply an index to a sum of columns `T1.a + T2.b`? I recently got a question involving this index and was quite surprised, as the question was not whether it was possible (which I believe is not), but rather would it speed up some example query.
If it is possible, what exactly are we indexing? Would it be helpful in queries like `WHERE T1.a+T2.b = 3` or in some other cases? Thanks!

Comment: Index are product specific, which dbms are you using?

Comment: The question was supposed to be implementation-independent, and applicable to all dbms-s. Let's say Oracle though, as that is what I believe the asker is using on a daily basis

Comment: But it isn't applicable to all dbms's.

Comment: if the goal is to speed up that query, then an index on the calculated part does not make too much sense.  - maybe make a materialized view for speed...

Comment: Could you provide some simple example where such index would speed up a query? Or would it be useless in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most (not all) database systems allow you to create an index on the result of an *expression*, so creating an index on the sum of two columns is possible in those systems.

> Would it be helpful in queries like `WHERE T1.a+T2.b = 3` or in some other cases?

That depends completely on the query and what plan the compiler decides to use to evaluate the query.  If you filter on the sum of two columns, and there are relatively few records that meet that criteria, then yes, an index will reduce the amount of scanning that needs to be done to find matching records.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL product, it could be possible to index a view which can contain a group by to get the persisted summary values.

**HOWEVER**

This is a local optimization (google "no free lunch"), as that it will result in faster select performance for you at the expense of slower inserts and updates for others.

Comment: So assuming it's possible in a given dbms, would that index speed up querying with the `WHERE` clause of `T1.a+T2.b=x`? Or would it be useful in some other case or not at all?